# Attach an association callback to all associations for a given model at once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Suppose there's an Account model with multiple associations related to a User table, e.g.:

```rb
class Account < ActiveRecord
  has_many :users
  has_many :clients, ..., :source => :user
  has_many :managers, ..., :source => :user
end
```

If I use `.delete()` with any one of these associations it will delete the existing relationship between the account and the user. I want to register a callback when this relationship gets deleted. I can append each has_many declaration with `:before_remove => :callback`, but I'm wondering if there's any shortcut that will automatically add the callback to every existing association where source is set to `:user`.

Comment: Do you try add the callback to `has_many :users` and check if it works for all?

Comment: @FeifeiXiong yes, I tried - doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There is no such option. Probably because its a not a great idea as it would really increase the complexity and cause tons of undesirable side effects.

And its also not needed since you can achieve the same thing by decorating the method:

```
module MyApp
  module Assocations

    def self.included(base)
      base.extend ClassMethods
    end

    module ClassMethods
      def decorate_association(**options, &block)
         yield AssocationDecorator.new(self, options)
      end
    end

    class AssocationDecorator
      attr_accessor :options, :klass
      def initialize(klass, **options)
        @klass = klass
        @options = options
      end
      def has_many(name, scope = nil, **options, &extension)
        @klass.has_many(name, scope, options.reverse_merge(@options), &extension)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

```
class Account < ActiveRecord
  include MyApp::Assocations
  decorate_association(before_remove: :callback, source: :user) do |decorator|
    decorator.has_many :clients
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you, I ended up doing something similar